# How to override order sales model in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml

I have stuck with this. I am trying to override sales/ order model _saveafter function with my custom module. I have the following code

\app\code\local\Rkt\SalesNew\etc\config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Rkt_SalesNew>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Rkt_SalesNew>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
 <salesnew>
      <rewrite>
        <method>Rkt_SalesNew_Model_Order</method>
      </rewrite>
 </salesnew>
    </models>
</global>
```

\app\code\local\Rkt\SalesNew\Model\Order.php

```
class Rkt_SalesNew_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
```

{

```
   protected function _afterSave()
{ 
    if (null !== $this->_addresses) {
        $this->_addresses->save();
        $billingAddress = $this->getBillingAddress();
        $attributesForSave = array();
        if ($billingAddress && $this->getBillingAddressId() != $billingAddress->getId()) {
            $this->setBillingAddressId($billingAddress->getId());
            $attributesForSave[] = 'billing_address_id';
        }

        $shippingAddress = $this->getShippingAddress();
        if ($shippingAddress && $this->getShippigAddressId() != $shippingAddress->getId()) {
            $this->setShippingAddressId($shippingAddress->getId());
            $attributesForSave[] = 'shipping_address_id';
        }

        if (!empty($attributesForSave)) {
            $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, $attributesForSave);
        }

    }
    if (null !== $this->_items) {
        $this->_items->save();
    }
    if (null !== $this->_payments) {
        $this->_payments->save();
    }
    if (null !== $this->_statusHistory) {
        $this->_statusHistory->save();
    }
    foreach ($this->getRelatedObjects() as $object) {
        $object->save();
    } 
    return parent::_afterSave();
}

}
```

I am unable to override this function. Can any one please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite abstract class just need to copy `Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract` file to `community` or `local` pool.

And after that, you can edit that file in that scope. autoload functionality will load files from following orders:
 1. lib
 2. core
 3. community
 4. local

`app > code > community > Mage > Sales > Model > Abstract.php`

Comment: Please click on up arrow near my answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/307347/57334 @Anton

Answer (score 0):

`_afterSave` method is not defined in abstract class, it's in main `Order` class itself.
Your config.xml file is wrong for rewrite declaration, it should be something like this (only relevant part added here ) :

```
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <order>Rkt_SalesNew_Model_Order</order>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
</models>
```

And lastly, you'll be need to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class, not the abstract class.

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/307347/57334 @Prateek