# Magento 1.9 - How to add if-else condition on Sales order email template HTML file?

Tags: email-templates, html, magento1.9.2.3, if

Following is my sales order email template sample,

Docroot = app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
                        <h1>Thank you for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>     
                        <p>Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below. Thank you again for your business.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="store-info">
                        <h4>Order Questions?</h4>
                        <p>
                            {{depend store_phone}}
                            <b>Call Us:</b>
                            <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_hours}}
                            <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_email}}
                            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                            {{/depend}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I just want to alter my thank you message based on the website in my multistore website.

**If website id  == 1** my message should be

```
<h1>Thank you for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
```

**else**

```
<h1>Welcome our land your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use direct `if` condition like this

```
{{if order.websiteid == 1}}
 <p>Your text goes here</p>
{{/if}}
```

But you can define the function or flag in your order model like this.

with function

```
public function shouldShowBlock() {
        /* your code to check website condition and return true or false */
    }
```

and in email template

```
    {{if order.shouldShowBlock()}}
 <p>Your text goes here</p>
{{/if}}
```

Just copy app/code/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php to app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php then write you function to end of that file

Comment: may i know how to write order mode and where to write itl?

Comment: For your kind attention, i am using Magento version 1.9

Comment: ohh then you can get reference from here https://kiwee.eu/magento-how-to-override-core-model-class/

Comment: app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales how to take the model?

Comment: didn't get your above comment

Comment: My file under app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html how should be like my local path like app/code/local/Kiwee/MyModule/models/Order.php

Comment: I am asking to override php class file not html

Comment: Just copy `app/code/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` then write you function to end of that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105675/discussion-between-zus-and-zaheerabbas).

Comment: Shall i use same for app\locale\en_US\template\email\html\footer.html ?

Comment: No, you can't because order object not be available on that template

Comment: Any other alternate way?

Comment: Please ask separate question so the community may suggest the way to do so